# Ruby Mongo DB multiple records of same value

Tags: ruby, mongodb, uuid

I'm new to MongoDB and databases in general.  I'm using Ruby and I would like to query against a specific UUID in the database.

The ID is stored as _id and the value is '101b437a-be16-44f6-b0b0-0201cdee6510'

I have the following that usually queries my database:

```
  field = '_id:'
  value =  101b437a-be16-44f6-b0b0-0201cdee6510

  def query_field(field,value)
  query = {#{field}: value}

  @result = @mongo_interface.get(query)
  expect(@result.count).to be >= 1
  puts "Number of matched values:  #{@result.count}"

end


def get(param_hash, collection_name = nil)
   col_name = (collection_name.nil? || collection_name.empty?) ? @collection : collection_name
@docs = @db[col_name].find(param_hash)
```

end

When I look within the _id field, I'm assuming it's stored as some sort of binary key and thus isn't found using my search.

Is there some conversion I could/should do to make the query above work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ODM like [Mongoid](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.1.0/mongoid-installation/) will ease your pain. Add it to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'mongoid'
```

and run `bundle install`. Make sure you skimmed through the installation guide to add all the necessary configs.
Then include the following line to your model/class, say:

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
end
```

You'll be able to query the records like `Product.find(id)` right after.

Comment: Have you tried looking through [Mongoid Installation Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/6.1.0/mongoid-installation/)?

Comment: Hi there, I've been looking and to be honest I'm not sure I was going down the right route for the test.  I was drilling into the Event Store which isn't ideal.  I have started using MongoID for my tests though. Thanks for hthe heads up

Comment: @Tom I've just created [a sample Rails 5 application](https://github.com/dskecse/rails_mongodb) configured to use MongoDB with an example resource and some specs.